# http request in ios mvc pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm working on an application to create an HTTP request from ios to a server. I'm confused that whether the HTTP request will be called from the viewcontroller or model. I would be happy if I can get some tutorials on this.

Comment: Have you tried either ?

Comment: Networking call should be from a ViewController or corresponding manager classes, not from the model.

Answer (score 1):

Make the request from the view controller. If it is successful, use the response data to create your models. A model is essentially just an instance of your object that holds data. If you were to make the call from your model you would have to initialize it before you have the data. This is not to say that it isn't *technically* possible to do this but it is better to use the controller.

Make request from view controller --> use response to get a model object --> use model to update view

There's tons of info on MVC available and apple has a bunch of docs as well. You can start here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html.

Comment: Communication: User actions in the view layer that create or modify data are communicated through a controller object and result in the creation or updating of a model object. When a model object changes (for example, new data is received over a network connection), it notifies a controller object, which updates the appropriate view objects.   this is what given in the above link provided. Please clarify.....